# Android - find out default sharedUserId

Tags: android

I have an app that is already published. Now I want to create plugins for it that have special permissions so that the main app does not require permissions not everyone wants to give it.

**Question**

As I did not declare a `sharedUserId` and changing it does change the UID, I want to find out the default `sharedUserId` generated by android studio

Answer (score 1):

Android-Studio did not generate a shared-user-id - if you did not specify one -> there was none. As far as I know it is not possible to add a shared-user-id afterwards without breaking the update path

Comment: Does using no `sharedUserId` as well? Or will this fail?

Comment: I thought you are using no sharedUserId at the moment? *confused*

Comment: I am. I just wanted to know if this it work as well, if my plugins use no `sharedUserId`. As this may be considered as equal `sharedUserId`...